# Fail to compile program using boost::spirit with Intel C++ compiler

Tags: c++, boost, icc

I'm trying to compile the following example http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/spirit/example/qi/compiler_tutorial/calc3.cpp using Intel C++ compiler.

Compilation fails and I get 300 kB of errors. The first few are:

```
boost/fusion/container/vector/vector.hpp(69): error: namespace "boost::fusion::vector_detail::result_of" has no member "value_at_c"
          : boost::is_convertible<Sequence, typename result_of::value_at_c<This, 0>::type>
                                                                ^
boost/fusion/container/vector/vector.hpp(69): error: expected a ">"
          : boost::is_convertible<Sequence, typename result_of::value_at_c<This, 0>::type>
                                                                          ^
boost/fusion/container/vector/vector.hpp(69): error: not a class or struct name
          : boost::is_convertible<Sequence, typename result_of::value_at_c<This, 0>::type>
            ^
```

Command line is

```
icl.exe /I<path-to-boost> calc3.cpp
```

Boost version: 1.60, compiler version: 15.0.6.285 Build 20151119

Although I was able to fix the error by changing the line 69

```
struct is_convertible_to_first
        : boost::is_convertible<Sequence, typename result_of::value_at_c<This, 0>::type>
    {};
```

to

```
struct is_convertible_to_first
        : boost::is_convertible<Sequence, typename boost::fusion::result_of::value_at_c<This, 0>::type>
    {};
```

,
I'm still curious why is there a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most reasonable guess is that the `result_of` namespace that ICC finds *within* `boost::fusion::vector_detail` is only a workaround for non-conforming compilers (e.g. I think GCC 4.6 lacks some support there too) so, the name clash with `boost::fusion::result_of` only manifests there.

So it's a bug reportable with the library devs; the namespace should be qualified more to accomodate old compilers.  (It's possible it won't be fixed anymore if said compilers aren't supported)